# Disabling the head from tracking the executed trajectory of the arm

Tags: ros, move-arm

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When using the [move_arm](http://www.ros.org/wiki/move_arm) package, the head would track the arm moving along the collision-free trajectory it found. I was wondering if there was an option to switch this functionality off since it would be great if the head kept looking at the target and not have to abruptly monitor the arm once the trajectory is found.

Did anyone figure out how to solve this issue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10763/disabling-the-head-from-tracking-the-executed-trajectory-of-the-arm/) by [Nash](https://answers.ros.org/users/130/nash/) on ROS Answers with karma: 207 on 2011-07-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think there is no explicit ros parameter for disabling head tracking, but if you just set the parameter `head_monitor_link` to empty or delete it, moving the head should be disabled.

You have several ways to set the corresponding parameters. You can either build up your own launch file by copying and adjusting e.g. move_right_arm.launch or you can create your own launch file that might look like this:

```
<launch>
  <include file="$(find pr2_arm_navigation_actions/launch/move_right_arm.launch>
  <param name="/move_right_arm/head_monitor_link"
         type="str"
         value=""/>
</launch>
```

This exploits the evaluation order of launch files. Later parameter definitions can overwrite earlier ones.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2011-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nash](https://answers.ros.org/users/130/nash/) on 2011-07-29**:
That makes sense..Thanks!

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2011-07-28**:
I actually would not change one of Willow Garage's makefiles. In my case, I created my own launch file for starting up move_arm and grasping actions. You can also create your own launch file that just includes move_right_arm.launch and overwrites the parameters. See my updated answer.

**Comment by [Nash](https://answers.ros.org/users/130/nash/) on 2011-07-28**:
Thanks Lorenz, Just to confirm, I would have to change that particular link in the pr2_arm_navigation_actions/launch/move_right_arm.launch for the just for right arm. I will try it on the robot tomorrow!